# TypeScript: Reference subtype of type definition (interface)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing

I am using the following type in my TypScript:

```
interface ExerciseData {
    id : number;
    name : string;
    vocabulary : {
        from : string;
        to : string;
    }[];
}
```

Now I'd like to create a variable that is of the same type as the attribute `vocabulary`, trying the following:

```
var vocabs : ExerciseData.vocabulary[];
```

But that is not working. Is it possible to reference to a subtype somehow? Or would I have to do something like this?

```
interface ExerciseData {
    id : number;
    name : string;
    vocabulary : Vocabulary[];
}

interface Vocabulary {
        from : string;
        to : string;
}

var vocabs : Vocabulary[];
```

Thanks a lot for hints.

Comment: You are correct. You should do what you did in the last code block.

Comment: Thank you @WayneEllery - so you would say this is definitely not possible?

Comment: Yeah. You should really declare your types anyway.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can reference interface subtypes using *lookup types*, added in TypeScript 2.1:

```
interface ExerciseData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    vocabulary: Array<{
        from: string;
        to: string;
    }>;
}

type Name = ExerciseData['name']; // string
```

These lookup types can also be chained. So to get the type of a vocabulary item you can do this:

```
type Vocabulary = ExerciseData['vocabulary'][number]; // { from: string; to: string; }
```

Or with even more chaining, the `from` field:

```
type From = ExerciseData['vocabulary'][number]['from']; // string
```

For complex scenarios it's also possible to base the lookup type on another type. For example, on a string literal union type:

```
type Key = 'id' | 'name';
type FieldTypes = ExerciseData[Key]; // number | string
```

Comment: Any way of do this dinamically? Like in JS ExerciseData[xxx][]

Comment: How about if you want to access a child of vocabulary, can thus be chained?

Comment: @xperiments I have added an example of basing the lookup type on another type. If with dynamically you actually meant using a string value, then no, it wouldn't be possible because the TypeScript compiler cannot know what that value will be in runtime.

Comment: @Buts Yes, this is possible. I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found it's working in the next way these days:

```
interface User {
  avatar: string;
}

interface UserData {
  someAvatar: User['avatar'];
}
```

very useful if you don't want to export all the things.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what you want but you can hack around this with the typof keyword but only if you have a var that is declared as your interface type like below. Note that I think what you did in your last codeblock is a lot better :)

```
interface ExerciseData {
    id : number;
    name : string;
    vocabulary : {
        from : string;
        to : string;
    }[];
}
var x: ExerciseData;
var vocabs : typeof x.vocabulary[];
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's a quite interesting possibility indeed - though not quite what I was looking for. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

Something to keep in mind if you are trying to access by `Interface['index']`, but `index` is possibly `undefined` (optional).

Note the `vocabulary?` below:

```js
interface ExerciseData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    vocabulary?: {
        from: string;
        to: string;
    }[];
}
```

Use the [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type like so...

```js
type Test = {
    prop: NonNullable<ExerciseData['vocabulary']>[number]['from']
}
```