# TypeScript: Reference subtype of a nullable type definition

Tags: typescript

From some code generate tool, I got some type definition similar to

```js
type ParentType = {
  viewer : {
    userByUuid: {
      username: string | null;
      legalName: string | null;
    } | null;
  } | null;
}
```

And I want to be able to refer to the type similar to

```js
type User = {
    username: string | null;
    legalName: string | null;
} | null;
```

I know if the `ParentType` is not nullable, I can use a way similar to

```js
type User = ParentType['viewer']['userByUuid']
```

But how can I handle this type reference for the nullable type?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Reference subtype of type definition (interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875483/typescript-reference-subtype-of-type-definition-interface)

Comment: @KiranMistry Thanks for this link. I always saw it before asking the question, but did not find the right way to handle the null case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional types to extract the non `null` part,

```js
type ParentType = {
    viewer : {
      userByUuid: {
        username: string | null;
        legalName: string | null;
      } | null;
    } | null;
  }

type NonNullableType<T> = T extends null ? never : T
type Viewer = NonNullableType<ParentType["viewer"]>
type User = NonNullableType<Viewer["userByUuid"]>
```

Comment: TypeScript also has a built-in `NonNullable` type. It's defined in the `lib.d.ts` as `type NonNullable<T> = T & {};`